# How do you declare an extern "C" function pointer

Tags: c++, function-pointers, boost-bind

So I have this code:

```
#include "boost_bind.h"
#include <math.h>
#include <vector>
#include <algorithm>

double foo(double num, double (*func)(double)) {
  return 65.4;
}

int main(int argc, char** argv) {
  std::vector<double> vec;
  vec.push_back(5.0);
  vec.push_back(6.0);
  std::transform(vec.begin(), vec.end(), vec.begin(), boost::bind(foo, _1, log));
}
```

And receive this error:

```
        return unwrapper<F>::unwrap(f, 0)(a[base_type::a1_], a[base_type::a2_]);
.............................................................^
%CXX-E-INCOMPATIBLEPRM, argument of type "double (* __ptr64 )(double) C" is
          incompatible with parameter of type "double (* __ptr64 )(double)"
          detected during:
            instantiation of ...5 pages of boost
```

So this error is because 'log' is extern "C"'d in math.h

I was wondering how to declare my function pointer argument in foo() so it handles extern "C"'d functions.

Comment: not that it answers your question, but this particular situation doesn't require `boost::bind`, `std::bind2nd` would do the job just fine.

Answer (score 25, accepted):

You can try including `cmath` instead, and using `static_cast<double(*)(double)>(std::log)` (cast necessary to resolve to the `double` overload).

Otherwise, you will limit your function to `extern C` functions. This would work like

```
extern "C" typedef double (*ExtCFuncPtr)(double);

double foo(double num, ExtCFuncPtr func) {
  return 65.4;
}
```

Another way is to make `foo` a functor

```
struct foo {
  typedef double result_type;
  template<typename FuncPtr>
  double operator()(double num, FuncPtr f) const {
    return 65.4;
  }
};
```

Then you can pass `foo()` to `boost::bind`, and because it's templated, it will accept any linkage. It will also work with function objects, not only with function pointers.

Comment: Amazing, I tried with a functor but I didn't think of fixing it for all types with a template. Thanks

Answer (score 5):

Try using a typedef:

```
extern "C" {
  typedef double (*CDoubleFunc)(double);
}

double foo(double num, CDoubleFunc func) {
  return 65.4;
}
```