# How to declare a member as a pointer to an extern "C" function?

Tags: c++, linkage

I'm looking to declare the type of an extern "C" function pointer. It is a member variable. The syntax in [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1289191/how-do-declare-an-extern-c-function-pointer) I cannot get to compile.

```
template<typename Sig> struct extern_c_fp {
    extern "C" typedef typename std::add_pointer<Sig>::type func_ptr_type;
};
```

I have experimented with placing the `extern "C"` at both ends, and between `typedef` and `typename` and between `type` and `func_ptr_type`, but the compiler rejected all. Any suggestions?

Comment: With `extern "C"` alias templates, this would work. http://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg21/docs/cwg_active.html#1463

Comment: BTW You need `Sig` to be `extern "C"`. The pointer addition to the function type does not have the linkage. It's the function type itself. You induce the linkage when forming the function type. Not when naming an existing function type - that existing type has the linkage it has.

Comment: http://liveworkspace.org/code/768027ef00bb0a31e76d8d856ac50801 It complains less, but still problematic.

Comment: Unfortunately `extern "C" { template<typename T> struct A {}; }` is rejected by implementations. Instead of not applying the linkage to `A`, they try to apply it and violate the rule that templates shall not have C language linkage. IMHO such code is valid... language linkage does not apply to templates and hence the template will never have C language linkage. Such code would be useful!

Comment: Am I missing something here. Why are you trying to do this?

Comment: Is it possible to give C linkage to C++ methods/member functions or am I missing something? At first glance, it doesn't quite make sense to me.

Comment: It has nothing to do with a C++ method or member function. It's about having a member variable that is a function pointer, with the extern "C" calling convention.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
extern "C" {
    template<typename R, typename... Args>
    using extern_c_fp = R(*)(Args...);
}

using my_function_ptr = extern_c_fp<void, int, double>;
// returns void, takes int and double
```

This doesn’t use the same interface as you use, but there may be a way to extract the return type and argument types of `Sig`.

This works in clang 3.1. Xeo pointed out [it didn’t work in GCC](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/transcript/message/6080989#6080989). I’m not sure if this is a bug in either compiler, so be careful when using this.

Answer (score 0):

You cannot declare a typedef like that (from 7.5p4):

> A linkage-specification shall occur only in namespace scope (3.3).